# how to set up production credentials on behalf of third party

Tags: c#, credentials, production, docusignapi

we need some help in understanding how to set up the production side of the integration. I suspect that we may not be able to set this up in the way we had initially anticipated (although i am certain there is a workaround). As way of background:

we have written a custom application for our customer which is intended to allow the customer to send envelopes directly from the custom application we have written for them.

where we may have a problem, is that we initially anticipated that the envelopes could be sent using the customer's existing docusign account.

we are using the soap api with a c# application.  our testing credentials are set in c# as per the following pseudo code:

```
...
credentials.AccountId = " our account id here ";
credentials.UserName = "[ our integrator key here ]" + "our email address";
credentials.password = " our password ";
credentials.ApiUrl = " the demo api url ";
...

// elsewhere when we define the envelope we say

envelope.AccountId = " our account id here ";
```

now, in production this is what we would like to do:

```
...
credentials.AccountId = " our customer's account id here ";
credentials.UserName = "[ our integrator key here ]" + [our customer's send on behalf of email address] + "our email address";
credentials.password = " our customer's password ";  // or our password perhaps?
credentials.ApiUrl = " the production api url ";
...

// elsewhere when we define the envelope we would say

envelope.AccountId = " our customer's account id here ";
```

is what we are attempting even possible or must our customer move their account over to our account?

Comment: Were you able to get this to work based on my answer and comments below?  Thanks, -Ergin

Answer (score 0):

Have a look into Federation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb897402.aspx and reliant party trusts

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want is SOBO (Send On Behalf Of) functionality.  Go to the DocuSign Developer Center and on the Documentation page you see the api guides.

[DocuSign API Documentation](http://www.docusign.com/developer-center/documentation)

Since you're using SOAP either download the SOAP pdf or open the online version, and do a search for "behalf".  You'll see the SOBO page come up, which has the info you need to make this work.

This page in particular is the one I'm referencing:

[SOBO](http://www.docusign.com/p/APIGuide/Content/Introduction+Changes/Send%20On%20Behalf%20Of%20Functionality.htm)

Comment: my code example in my original question specifically includes the send on behalf of syntax (scroll to right). my question is:  whose account id do i use and where?  in other words, do my credentials only reference our integrator  key, name and password and everything else is the customer's account id and email? it seems confusing because it appears that 2 different accounts are involved.  is my example of what we would like to do correct?

Comment: If you have two users in the same account and you want one user (user A) to send on behalf of the other user (user B) you use all the credentials of user A but in the second set of square brackets put user B's email.  There's a section in the dev center that explains how to accomplish this, even though it uses REST API it still might help explain for you.  Please see [this page](http://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features/sobo)